# sshd restrict group by address and IP

Tags: sshd

We have one single group of users that we want to restrict to logging in only from a single specific host and no where else.  So basically, restrict ssh access by group AND by IP.  This user can only log in from hostA, they are denied when they try to log in from any where else.

I've read working with PAM, iptables, sshd deny groups / deny users / allow groups / allow users / match / using the "from" column in the authorized keys...

I'd prefer to of course just deal with sshd configs rather than try to do this with 3 other applications...  I've tried editing the sshd configs (and after restarting) none of the "deny / allow / match" parameters seem to work to restrict a user from this group from logging onto the host.

```
### deny group deployment from everywhere except hostA

Match Address !12.34.56.78/32
        DenyGroups deployment
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a desire to do this - and the closest I could come to a solution is to use iptables with the cgroup extension.

```
man iptables-extensions
```

The command woupd look something like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m cgroup ! --cgroup $iprestrictedusergroup -j DROP
```